# CentOS 7 Linux Root / Mysterious 35GB Space /dev/mapper/centos-root

Tags: linux, centos, lvm, root-filesystem

I have read similar posts here and other forums for a while now but running out of ideas.

We have a few CentOS 7 Linux VMs running in our environment with 40 GB Root drives. A few months ago these started mysteriously filling up and have gone from 10GB usage to almost full 40GB. I have gone through tons of cmdlets regarding viewing largest directories/files, have been digging through directories manually and found nothing regarding the missing 30GB+.

- All I managed to find is the `/proc/kcore` 128TB file which apparently doesn't use any filesystem space.
- Then there's the `lastlog` which at some point came up as 80GB but again, it's a sparse file and doesn't use up any of the space.
- We did upgrade Veeam recently and it's advisable this file is excluded from backups, but so far found no evidence this is contributing to the missing space issue.

All cmdlets ran as root.

- Here's standard `df -h` output:

  ```
  Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
  /dev/mapper/centos-root   38G   38G  382M 100% /
  devtmpfs                 911M     0  911M   0% /dev
  tmpfs                    921M  304K  920M   1% /dev/shm
  tmpfs                    921M   97M  824M  11% /run
  tmpfs                    921M     0  921M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
  /dev/sda1                497M  163M  334M  33% /boot
  tmpfs                    185M     0  185M   0% /run/user/307804300
  tmpfs                    185M     0  185M   0% /run/user/0
  ```
- Output of `ls -la` on `/`:

  ```
  dr-xr-xr-x.  17 root root 4096 Apr 16 07:23 .
  dr-xr-xr-x.  17 root root 4096 Apr 16 07:23 ..
  lrwxrwxrwx.   1 root root   19 Nov 18  2017 bdcore.so -> bdcore.so.linux-x86
  lrwxrwxrwx.   1 root root    7 Feb 29  2016 bin -> usr/bin
  dr-xr-xr-x.   4 root root 4096 May  4 12:26 boot
  drwxr-xr-x.  19 root root 3120 Jul 10 12:11 dev
  drwxr-xr-x.  86 root root 8192 May 18 13:41 etc
  drwxr-xr-x.  23 root root 4096 Jul  9 12:01 home
  lrwxrwxrwx.   1 root root    7 Feb 29  2016 lib -> usr/lib
  lrwxrwxrwx.   1 root root    9 Feb 29  2016 lib64 -> usr/lib64
  drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root    6 Aug 12  2015 media
  dr-xr-xr-x.  17 root root 4096 Apr 16 07:23 mnt
  drwxr-xr-x.   6 root root   74 Jun  8 09:23 opt
  dr-xr-xr-x. 116 root root    0 May 18 13:40 proc
  dr-xr-x---.   6 root root 4096 Jun 23  2017 root
  drwxr-xr-x.  22 root root  700 Jul 10 12:11 run
  lrwxrwxrwx.   1 root root    8 Feb 29  2016 sbin -> usr/sbin
  drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root    6 Aug 12  2015 srv
  dr-xr-xr-x.  13 root root    0 May 18 13:41 sys
  drwxrwxrwt.  10 root root 4096 Jul 10 12:33 tmp
  drwxr-xr-x.  13 root root 4096 Feb 29  2016 usr
  drwxr-xr-x.  21 root root 4096 May 18 13:41 var
  ```
- Output of `du / -xh 2> /dev/null | sort -hr | head -n 20`:

  ```
  3.2G    /
  1.7G    /opt
  1.4G    /opt/BitDefender
  1.2G    /usr
  1.2G    /opt/BitDefender/var
  971M    /opt/BitDefender/var/lib
  656M    /opt/BitDefender/var/lib/scan
  474M    /usr/lib
  358M    /usr/share
  353M    /opt/BitDefender/var/lib/scan/antivirus_9647
  343M    /opt/BitDefender/var/lib/scan/antivirus_9647/Plugins
  313M    /var
  303M    /opt/BitDefender/var/lib/scan/base
  293M    /opt/BitDefender/var/lib/scan/base/Plugins
  241M    /opt/SolarWinds/Agent/bin
  241M    /opt/SolarWinds/Agent
  241M    /opt/SolarWinds
  236M    /opt/BitDefender/var/log
  226M    /usr/lib/modules
  215M    /opt/BitDefender/var/lib/modules
  ```

As you can see, the space doesn't add up.

Tried mounting `/` to another location via `mount -o bind / /mnt` but getting the same results with `du -h /mnt`

`lsof +L1` returns nothing - there were some files held there originally but tiny and the processes have been killed off since.

Really appreciate your feedback.

UPDATE: LVM Outputs

```
--- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/centos/swap
  LV Name                swap
  VG Name                centos
  LV UUID                LXe5pc-42IG-PA2F-RcQB-7lmC-XDPy-5TgPSN
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time localhost, 2016-02-29 15:03:40 +0000
  LV Status              available
  # open                 2
  LV Size                2.00 GiB
  Current LE             512
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     8192
  Block device           253:1

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/centos/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                centos
  LV UUID                fKThWr-G0xn-gfka-rDcc-u029-sZ1Y-h3g5Bx
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time localhost, 2016-02-29 15:03:41 +0000
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                37.50 GiB
  Current LE             9600
  Segments               3
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     8192
  Block device           253:0




sudo pvdisplay
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sda2
  VG Name               centos
  PV Size               19.51 GiB / not usable 3.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              4994
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          4994
  PV UUID               CaFFWt-7Ayr-8slF-Kv5v-KBSZ-qfj4-AVp29w

  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sda3
  VG Name               centos
  PV Size               10.00 GiB / not usable 4.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              2559
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          2559
  PV UUID               KVwyje-5tui-tAiB-JV1J-8L3G-Us3p-2AoyHf

  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sda4
  VG Name               centos
  PV Size               10.00 GiB / not usable 4.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              2559
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          2559
  PV UUID               WAgPfw-jXxn-gAhS-hhe7-u1Ig-P9D3-ljPCjn

pvs
 PV         VG     Fmt  Attr PSize  PFree
  /dev/sda2  centos lvm2 a--  19.51g    0
  /dev/sda3  centos lvm2 a--  10.00g    0
  /dev/sda4  centos lvm2 a--  10.00g    0
```

`lsof -n | grep deleted` returns no results as already killed all PIDs holding on to deleted files

```
ps aux

USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.0  4.0 116548 76760 ?        Ss   May18  19:50 /usr/lib/system
root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    May18   0:01 [kthreadd]
root         3  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    May18   1:01 [ksoftirqd/0]
root         7  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    May18   0:00 [migration/0]
root         8  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    May18   0:00 [rcu_bh]
root         9  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    May18   0:00 [rcuob/0]
root        10  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    May18   9:58 [rcu_sched]
root        11  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    May18  15:31 [rcuos/0]
root        12  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    May18   0:14 [watchdog/0]
root        13  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   May18   0:00 [khelper]
root        14  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    May18   0:00 [kdevtmpfs]
root        15  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   May18   0:00 [netns]
root        16  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   May18   0:00 [perf]
root        17  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   May18   0:00 [writeback]
root        18  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   May18   0:00 [kintegrityd]
root        19  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   May18   0:00 [bioset]
root        20  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   May18   0:00 [kblockd]
root        21  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   May18   0:00 [md]
root        26  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    May18   0:02 [khungtaskd]
root        27  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    May18  16:30 [kswapd0]
root        28  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   May18   0:00 [ksmd]
root        30  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    May18   0:00 [fsnotify_mark]
root        31  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   May18   0:00 [crypto]
root        39  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   May18   0:00 [kthrotld]
root        41  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   May18   0:00 [kmpath_rdacd]
root        42  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   May18   0:00 [kpsmoused]
root        44  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   May18   0:00 [ipv6_addrconf]
root        63  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   May18   0:00 [deferwq]
root        93  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    May18   0:24 [kauditd]
root       259  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    May18   0:00 [scsi_eh_0]
root       260  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   May18   0:00 [ata_sff]
root       261  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   May18   0:00 [scsi_tmf_0]
root       262  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    May18   0:00 [scsi_eh_1]
root       264  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   May18   0:00 [events_power_e
root       265  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   May18   0:00 [vmw_pvscsi_wq_
root       266  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   May18   0:00 [scsi_tmf_1]
root       270  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    May18   0:00 [scsi_eh_2]
root       271  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   May18   0:00 [scsi_tmf_2]
root       276  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   May18   0:00 [ttm_swap]
root       398  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   May18   0:00 [kdmflush]
root       399  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   May18   0:00 [bioset]
root       410  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   May18   0:00 [kdmflush]
root       411  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   May18   0:00 [bioset]
root       424  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   May18   0:00 [xfsalloc]
root       425  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   May18   0:00 [xfs_mru_cache]
root       426  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   May18   0:00 [xfs-buf/dm-0]
root       427  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   May18   0:00 [xfs-data/dm-0]
root       428  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   May18   0:00 [xfs-conv/dm-0]
root       429  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   May18   0:00 [xfs-cil/dm-0]
root       430  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    May18  10:51 [xfsaild/dm-0]
root       502  0.0  0.1  36816  3524 ?        Ss   May18   8:04 /usr/lib/system
root       525  0.0  0.0 276600   556 ?        Ss   May18   0:00 /usr/sbin/lvmet
root       527  0.0  0.0  46800    20 ?        Ss   May18   0:00 /usr/lib/system
root       566  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   May18   0:00 [xfs-buf/sda1]
root       567  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   May18   0:00 [xfs-data/sda1]
root       568  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   May18   0:00 [xfs-conv/sda1]
root       569  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   May18   0:00 [xfs-cil/sda1]
root       571  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    May18   0:00 [xfsaild/sda1]
root       621  0.0  0.0 116744   156 ?        S<sl May18   1:37 /sbin/auditd -n
dbus       646  0.0  0.0  47392   944 ?        Ssl  May18   9:10 /bin/dbus-daemo
ntp        648  0.0  0.0  43808   512 ?        Ss   May18   0:14 /usr/sbin/ntpd
root       651  0.0  0.0 323972  1648 ?        Ssl  May18   1:26 /usr/bin/python
root       652  0.0  0.1 375400  3092 ?        Ssl  May18   2:51 /usr/sbin/rsysl
root       657  0.0  0.0 258988  1872 ?        Ss   May18  40:04 /usr/bin/vmtool
root       697  0.0  0.0 255680   264 ?        Ss   May18   1:16 /usr/sbin/sssd
root       698  0.0  1.5 502648 29232 ?        S    May18   2:32 /usr/libexec/ss
root       766  0.0  0.0 261508  1540 ?        S    May18   8:36 /usr/libexec/ss
root       767  0.0  0.0 246800  1548 ?        S    May18   0:28 /usr/libexec/ss
root       769  0.0  0.0  36692  1008 ?        Ss   May18   4:36 /usr/lib/system
root       771  0.0  0.0 126328   412 ?        Ss   May18   1:15 /usr/sbin/crond
root       773  0.0  0.0 443092  1664 ?        Ssl  May18   3:02 /usr/sbin/Netwo
root       851  0.0  0.0  53056     0 ?        Ss   May18   0:00 /usr/sbin/wpa_s
polkitd    854  0.0  0.0 540536  1244 ?        Ssl  May18   2:11 /usr/lib/polkit
root      1146  0.0  0.0 211620   476 ?        Sl   May18  13:56 /opt/BitDefende
root      1156  0.0  0.0 686628    44 ?        Sl   May18   6:08 /opt/BitDefende
root      1173  0.0  0.5 994932  9648 ?        Sl   May18  46:11 /opt/BitDefende
root      1205  0.3  0.1 576104  2644 ?        Sl   May18 304:22 /opt/BitDefende
root      1222  0.0  0.0 356520   340 ?        Sl   May18  17:25 /opt/BitDefende
root      1378  0.3  0.9 271152 17536 ?        Sl   May18 231:29 /opt/BitDefende
root      1435  0.0  0.0  30676     0 ?        Ss   May18   0:00 /usr/sbin/oddjo
root      1437  0.0  0.0 553064   912 ?        Ssl  May18   5:53 /usr/bin/python
root      1442  0.0  0.0  82548   264 ?        Ss   May18   0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd
root      2075  0.0  0.0  93212   168 ?        Ss   May18   0:25 /usr/libexec/po
postfix   2102  0.0  0.0 103660   152 ?        S    May18   0:09 qmgr -l -t unix
root      2340  0.3 44.0 2221756 830468 ?      Sl   Jun10 139:50 /opt/BitDefende
root      2488  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Jun10   0:00 [bd_edr_wq]
root      2489  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jun10   0:46 [consumer threa
root      2774  0.2  6.0 969012 114252 ?       Sl   May18 202:31 python /opt/Sap
root      3268  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    19:11   0:00 [kworker/u2:1]
root      3304  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        R    19:11   0:00 [kworker/0:33]
root      3305  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    19:11   0:00 [kworker/0:34]
postfix   3740  0.0  0.2 103480  3912 ?        S    19:17   0:00 pickup -l -t un
root      3749  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    19:17   0:00 [kworker/0:0]
root      3868  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    19:19   0:00 [kworker/u2:0]
root      4043  0.0  0.2 169804  5256 ?        Ss   19:19   0:00 sshd: 
  4064  0.0  0.1 169936  2400 ?        S    19:20   0:00 sshd: 
  4065  0.0  0.1 128360  2752 pts/0    Ss   19:20   0:00 -bash
  4351  0.0  0.0 161324  1832 pts/0    R+   19:23   0:00 ps aux
swiagent 12080  0.0  0.2 1179968 4252 ?        Ssl  May21  53:42 /opt/SolarWinds
swiagent 12103  0.2  0.4 687308  8904 ?        Sl   May21 161:57 /opt/SolarWinds
root     12253  0.0  0.0 110032     4 tty1     Ss+  May21   0:00 /sbin/agetty --
root     14743  0.1  0.1 170772  2012 ?        Ssl  Jun23  29:31 /usr/local/bin/
root     19408  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:10   0:00 [kworker/u2:2]
root     19591  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?       S<   16:11   0:00 [kworker/0:2H]
root     20130  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   10:50   0:00 [kworker/0:1H]
```

BD and SW agent have already been stopped/removed in a sandbox environment but this didn't reclaim any space

Comment: You are using LVM, and the volume uses the entire partition. So your real use can only be seen from inside the LVM.

Comment: I haven't found the LVM cmdlets helpful to determine what's taking up the space :( Do you mean LVM somehow reserves the space for the filesystem but isn't actually full?

Comment: LVM uses all of a partition, so yes. ` LV Size                37.50 GiB`

Comment: Please add to the question the output of `pvs`, `ps aux` and `lsof -n | grep deleted`

Comment: So is the df -h output accurate? It's claiming the LVM root is full, but is the 3.2 GB output all that's being used? Why would a system report this volume as full as well as the monitoring system? It ran out at times to the point where cmdlets were failing to execute due to lack of space, then it calmed down to just within the limit again. Just trying to understand what could suddenly start taking up this much space but running out of ideas where to look.

Comment: Sorry if I seemed short-tempered, I've spent ages looking at this having zero Linux exposure previously. I'm glad I leant so much anyways but really got stuck - any advice is greatly appreciated, I can try out anything needed in a sandbox environment!

Answer (score 1):

Try `fsck` to scan the filesystem

Comment: I rebooted several times and forced fsck during reboot - no corrupt files were found. Thanks tho!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Debian 10 in Hyper-V and Veeam.

When I built the server it was just a few GBs big. Now it is 121GB.

Some posts mentioned you could/should exclude the /proc/kcore, but I am curious what would happen if you needed to full restore this VM. Besides that, I use the Community edition of Veeam at home with Powershell so I use VeeamZIP which always makes full backups.

This VM was growing in time, backup after backup, but cannot see what started this.

I found a way combining all things together from searching Internet to these few steps in order to reduce the size of the VM-disk though.

### Compacting VM disks

On Linux CLI, first zero out all empty space before compating VHDX:

```
# cd /

# cat /dev/zero > zero.dat ; sync ; sleep 1 ; sync ; rm -f zero.dat
```

This last command is going to take a while, so be patient....

Now shutdown the VM, time for compacting the VM disks, start Powershell and run each command seperately:

```
Mount-VHD -Path "D:\Hyper-V\VM-LINUX\Virtual Hard Disks\VM-LINUX.vhdx" -ReadOnly

Optimize-VHD -Path "D:\Hyper-V\VM-LINUX\Virtual Hard Disks\VM-LINUX.vhdx" -Mode Full

Dismount-VHD -Path "D:\Hyper-V\VM-LINUX\Virtual Hard Disks\VM-LINUX.vhdx"
```

### Converting Linux VM disks

When adding a new Linux VM, most of us just create a new virtual disk, attach an downloaded ISO and start the installation.

I found out that there is more done with Powershell when it comes to Linux best practices on Hyper-V.

When creating dynamic disks, the default growth size is 32MB per step. For Linux 1MB would be better, so you will have to use Powershell for that.

But I am not in the mood to reinstall all my Linux VM's...

So let's convert them!

```
Convert-VHD -Path "D:\Hyper-V\VM-LINUX\Virtual Hard Disks\VM-LINUX.vhdx" -DestinationPath "D:\Hyper-V\VM-LINUX\Virtual Hard Disks\VM-LINUX-new.vhdx" -BlockSizeBytes 1MB
```

Once the disk is converted, simply go into settings of your VM and select the disk, browse to the new disk and apply. Hyper-V will then properly set the security setting of the file.

After compacting, and this conversion my Linux disk with the huge /proc/kcore file reduced from 121GB to 3,5GB!

There must be a similair way for VMWare too I guess.